# Question related to super() with __init__()

Tags: python, super

Given 3 classes below,

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('A')
    def test(self):
        print('1')

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B,self)        ## if .__init__() is not given here
        print('B')

class C(B, A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
        print('C')
```

If I run `D = C()`, it will return

```
B
C
```

If I run `print(C.__mro__)`,
it will gives `(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)`.
I think that means class A will be executed as it is inside the `mro` list.However, this is not the case.

I want ask why `.__init__()` is necessary for `A.__init__()` happening.

Comment: `super(B,self)` is a "no-op", it simply constructs a *proxy object* that refers to the next class in the *method resolution order*.

Answer (score 9):

That is *not* what it means!

I think you are actually confused about two things: what `mro` is, and the nature of subclass constructors in Python. Let's look at `mro` first.

`mro` means "method resolution order", and specifies the order in which the Python interpreter will look for appropriately named methods.

So, say you have the following class hierarchy:

```
class A:
    
    def deepest(self):
        print('I wonder where this is coming from...')
    
    def deeper(self):
        print('deeper from A')
    
    def deep(self):
        print('deep from A')

class B(A):
    
    def deeper(self):
        print('deeper from B')
    
    def deep(self):
        print('deep from B')

class C(B):
    
    def deep(self):
        print('deep from C')
        
c = C()
c.deep()
c.deeper()
c.deepest()
print(c.__mro__)
```

Output:

```
deep from C
deeper from B
I wonder where this is coming from...
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

When we call `deep`, Python looks for it in `C`, since `C` is first in the `mro`. It finds it and goes no further.

On the other hand, for `deeper`, Python cannot find it in `C` and therefore goes to the next one in the hierarchy, which is `B`, and finds it.

Same thing for `deepest`, which is only found in `A`.

Now, let's connect this to `__init__`.

In this case, when you call `__init__` from `super`, Python looks for the first superclass in the hierarchy, which is `B`, and calls its `__init__` method.

However, if the `__init__` method of `B` does not call `A.__init__`, *then the chain stops there*!

Unlike other languages, subclasses do not automatically call the `__init__` method of their superclasses, unless of course they have not defined their own `__init__` methods, then it is a case of `c.deeper()`, as above.

This is in line with Python's philosophy of "we're all consenting adults here" - if you don't want to call the superclass's `__init__`, then sure, do it, but you bear the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

```py
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        print('A.__init__()')

class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        print('B.__init__()')
        super().__init__() # this will call A.__init__()
b = B()
```

Because this is python behaviour. If you have `A` and `B` class and `A` is parent of `B` and `B` also has `__init__` method, you should call `A.__init__` manually. Otherwise, python will override it. You need explicit call !

We have `__init__` in python (Something like constructor). You should call it manually in some cases. It's not called automatically as it's in other languages.